# AWS Lambda C# Http Request connection problem

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm currently trying to do a http request to an endpoint inside my AWS account. This endpoint resides on a api controller from a MVC website.

The lambda isn't being able to send the request to the endpoint. The AWS Cloud Watch just don't show any errors ou any of my logs after the http call.

The AWS Lambda URL is HTTPs URL and the endpoint is a HTTP URL. Would be that a problem?

Please, help me!?

Comment: Yes.  When you use HTTPS a TLS authentication occurs and most likely the TLS is failing.  The HTTP doesn't get sent until the authentication completes which is why you do not see errors in the server log files.  Five years ago the industry decided to eliminate TLS 1.0/1.1 due to security issues and required clients to use TLS 1.2/1.3.  In June this year Microsoft did a security push to disable 1.0/1.1 on servers but did not do anything to fix clients.  Since August I've been answer this question 3 times a day.  So make sure you have a version of api controller that supports 1.2/1.3.

Comment: Is the Lambda in the same VPC as your resources / internal endpoint... Please post your network configuration.

Comment: Your client also need to send TLS 1.2/1.3 (stop sending 1.0/1.1).  If you do not specify in client the TLS version the default version base on a number of factors will be used.  You can see TLS version if you use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.